# React textarea is showing [object Object]

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to figure out why whenever I am typing in my textarea field it just returns [object Object] and not the value of what I am typing. In my parent component I used hooks and passed the different states to the child component as props.

```
 function RestaurantList({
      nearbyRestaurants,
      userReview,
      setUserReview,
      setQuery
    }) {
      function handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setUserReview({ ...userReview, [name]: value });
      }
    
      function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setQuery(userReview);
        setUserReview("");
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {nearbyRestaurants.map((place) => (
              <div>
                <li>
                  <div>{place.name}</div>
                  <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                    <input
                      type="text-area"
                      placeholder="Leave a review..."
                      value={userReview}
                      name="userReview"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <button className="submit-button" type="submit">
                      submit
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </li>
              </div>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: It probably shoud be setUserReview(value)

Comment: in the handleChange method you will get value from 'e.target.value' this

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to render an object, and when you convert Javascript objects to string it will convert to "`[object Object]`".

I think you are misunderstanding what the "name" prop of the input field should do in this context, you don't actually need that.

A better way of writing your handleChange function would be:

```js
function handleChange(e) {
    setUserReview(e.target.value);
}
```

This code fragment will set the state of `userReview` to the string that is currently in the textarea, instead of an object `{ userReview: string }` like before.

Note that this is not using the `name` prop.

There is also another error, `type="text-area"` is not a valid property of the `<input/>` tag. You should do like that:

```
 <textarea
    placeholder="Leave a review..."
    onChange={handleChange}
>
  {userReview}
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I previously did setUserReview to e.target.value. However, since I have multiple mapped list items every time I typed in one text area it would input that same text in the other textareas. This is when I tried to use the `name` prop but you are right I prob. am misunderstanding the name prop.

Comment: @JonLaboy in that case you are probably passing a single state getter/setter to all the components that takes an textarea. Each component should have its own state, so it won't act like "global"

Comment: I know that when I map through nearbyRestaurants it returns 5+ places each with a textarea. Then I set userReview(initially an empty string) to e.target.value. Like you said this makes it act "global." I just have to look into giving each one state and/or somehow differentiate them. I thought the `name` property would have done this but still yields the same result.

Comment: @JonLaboy Its a better idea to create another component named "RestaurantReview" that takes only a textarea, and this component will have the review/setReview state. So it won't share between all the restaurants. Each restaurant in your list will render its own RestaurantReview

Answer (score 1):

You're using invalid html:

```
<input type="text-area" />
```

[Textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) element is to be:

```
<textarea />
```

---

Okay, I found the issue with the userReview state. You should use:

```
<textarea onChange...>
  {userReview.userReview} /* name of the userReview state */
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is fine, but it doesn't have anything to do with the [object Object] problem OP is describing.

Comment: I have not found any issue with the OP code rather than issue with the html. So, just replacing with correct html should work fine. Maybe the [object object] issue is coming out due to invalid html.

Comment: NathanPB describes the issue in his answer. The problem in OP's code is that the userReview state is set to an object hence the textarea showing [object Object].

Comment: I do not agree  with that. OP code is perfectly okay.

Comment: If you replace it with a textarea you will get the same result. If you actually try it out you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Bhojendra that worked! However now my submitForm function is not working :/

Comment: @JonLaboy That's another problem. You can't do `setUserReview("");`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I tried setUserReview({ userReview: "" }) - this does clear it but it clears all the other textAreas as well. I know it's because this makes the forms' textareas' value point to same userReview object. But I don't know how to have separate object/variable for each form.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar any tips on what I can use instead of `setUserReview(");` ?